# Converting array(varchar) to varchar in athena/presto

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

How would I convert array(varchar) to varchar in athena/presto?

My array(varchar) data looks something like this

| col_1 | col_2 |
| --- | --- |
| [hello_world] | [hello_hello] |

It's in array(varchar) format as a result of applying the multimap_agg function when the table was previously created.

When I try this command:

```
select cast(col_1 as varchar) from table
```

I get the following error message:

> SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:8: Cannot cast array(varchar) to varchar

How would I achieve this using Athena/Presto

Thanks

Comment: Your examples only ever contain one element, so why not just use  `element_at()`? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/accessing-array-elements.html

Answer (score 2):

To convert an array to a atring, use `array_join()`:

```
select [array_join(col_1, ' ')][1]
```

Comment: Yes, exactly: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/converting-arrays-to-strings.html